# Flickering images

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'm currently making a little game where every few seconds some images are removed and reloaded to update their new status and position, which is done with the code below. However, this causes these images to flicker at every reload which is especially annoying when an image is on the exact same spot and can actually cause a miss-click now and then. Is there any way I can prevent my images from flickering?

```
$(".armysprite").remove();

for (var i = 0; i < armies.length; i++) {
    iniArmies(i); // Function that adds the new army images back into the DOM
}
```

Comment: The code inside iniArmies would help...

Comment: Its not that exciting, the only relevant code in there is:

    army.avatar = gf.addImg(army.div, "army" + index, useless info});

Which then refers to this:

gf.addImg = function(parent, divId, options){
    // useless info
    parent.append(img);
}

The issue is probably that the images are removed and then reloaded with a noticeable gap of time in between.

Comment: Perhaps just updating the images that change while in the loop could a) speed things up and b) reduce any flickr since fewer images are being updated/refreshed

Comment: Use an image sprite, move the image position rather than loading another asset, this way it won't flicker while it loads another resource from the server.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to do it is: to load new image in hidden div, and on the function of `onload` of the image to show this `div` and hide your old `div` (like css property: `display:none;` / `display:block;`)

Comment: It's `display:none`, not `display:hide`.